# Applying Street Labels in OpenLayers 5?

Tags: labeling, openlayers

I am trying to replicate https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/street-labels.html?q=label plotting highways over California, both from GeoJSON.  The Vienna labels show, but my CA highway labels don't.

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent.js';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps.js';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';
import {Fill, Style, Text, Stroke} from 'ol/style.js';
import {fromLonLat, toLonLat} from 'ol/proj.js';

  var style = new Style({
    text: new Text({
      font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
      placement: 'line',
      fill: new Fill({
        color: 'white'
      })
    })
  });

  var map = new Map({
    layers: [           
       new VectorLayer({
            source: new VectorSource({
                format: new GeoJSON(),
                url: '/vienna-streets.geojson'
            }),
            style: new Style({
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: "#CC0000",
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        }),
        new VectorLayer({
          declutter: true,
          source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            url: '/vienna-streets.geojson'
          }),
          style: function(feature) {
            style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
            return style;
          }
        }),
        new VectorLayer({
            source: new VectorSource({
                format: new GeoJSON(),
                url: '/hwy.geojson'
            }),
            style: new Style({
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: "#CC0000",
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        }),
        new VectorLayer({
          declutter: true,
          source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            url: '/hwy.geojson'
          }),
          style: function(feature) {
            style.getText().setText(feature.get('ROUTE'));
            return style;
          }
        })
     ],
     target: 'map',
      view: new View({
      zoom: 17,
    })
  });

  function CenterMap(long, lat) {
    var view = map.getView();
    var center = fromLonLat([long, lat]);
    view.setCenter(center);
    view.setZoom(9);
  }

  CenterMap(-122.27,37.75);
```

Both Vienna and Highway line features plot as symbols, and the two .geojson files look very similar to me: here's a sample feature from vienna-streets.geojson:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "5022444",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        16.4101713,
        48.2228049
      ],
      [
        16.4103365,
        48.2226838
      ],
      [
        16.410552,
        48.2225259
      ],
      [
        16.4107283,
        48.2224079
      ],
      [
        16.4110769,
        48.2221802
      ],
      [
        16.4115313,
        48.2218545
      ],
      [
        16.4118242,
        48.2216454
      ],
      [
        16.4121066,
        48.2214454
      ],
      [
        16.4128993,
        48.2208393
      ],
      [
        16.413,
        48.2208463
      ],
      [
        16.4131035,
        48.2208236
      ],
      [
        16.4143181,
        48.2199157
      ],
      [
        16.4143435,
        48.2198564
      ],
      [
        16.4143063,
        48.2197964
      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "foot": "yes",
    "highway": "cycleway",
    "name": "Praterl\u00e4nde",
    "segregated": "no",
    "surface": "paved"
  }
}
```

And here's one from hwy.geojson:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "ID": 322,
    "DISTRICT": 3,
    "COUNTY": "YOL",
    "ROUTE": 113,
    "ROUTE_SUFF": null,
    "RTE_GEOMID": "113_20150512_R",
    "BEGPM_PREF": "R",
    "BEGPM": 0,
    "BEG_ALIGN": null,
    "ENDPM_PREF": null,
    "ENDPM": 11.646,
    "END_ALIGN": null,
    "BEG_ODO": 22.26,
    "END_ODO": 33.752,
    "FROM_": "SOL CO LN",
    "TO": ".04M N\/CHURCHILL DOWNS AVE",
    "TYPE": "MAP 21 PRINCIPAL ARTERIAL",
    "NOTE": null
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        -121.765123584,
        38.694502981
      ],
      [
        -121.76512738339,
        38.694996918146
      ],
      [
        -121.76512753567,
        38.694998151658
      ],
      [
        -121.76519958233,
        38.695119493342
      ],
      [
        -121.76519974943,
        38.69512242402
      ],
      [
        -121.76521091857,
        38.69646055998
      ],
      [
        -121.76521094059,
        38.696463500298
      ],
      [
        -121.76521073741,
        38.696589642702
      ],
      [
        -121.76521073301,
        38.69659238132
      ],
      [
        -121.76520874399,
        38.69783007068
      ],
      [
        -121.76520873684,
        38.69783452274
      ],
      [
        -121.76520716216,
        38.69881395926
      ],
      [
        -121.76520715868,
        38.698816124148
      ],
      [
        -121.76520700032,
        38.698914801852
      ],
      [
        -121.76520703242,
        38.698916181099
      ],
      [
        -121.76522321172,
        38.699505549463
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Why does one datasource yield labels but the other does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two datasets is that the "name" attribute in the Vienna data is a string, whereas the "ROUTE" values are numbers.

Change

```
style.getText().setText(feature.get('ROUTE'));
```

to

```
style.getText().setText(feature.get('ROUTE').toString());
```

to convert the route numbers to strings before labeling.